Bars data label decimals are not the same as int he data
my data shows 2 decimals and the column type is set as fixed decimal number, because when i choose the type "decimal number" and round to 2 decimals, it still doe snot give the 2 decimals. the issue is with the bar chart, where the data labels on the bar shows incorrect decimals. I have data as 79.30% in the table , but bar shows as 79.00%.
How to fix it?
enter image description here
enter image description here
tried to adjust the decimal in data label but did not work
